# Pandas: .value_counts() is only counting incidents that are equal to the first row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table from an HTML page and import the data into a Pandas dataframe. The data source provides voting records from Canada's Parliament. This code successfully imports the data:

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.ourcommons.ca/Members/en/votes/43/2/32',header=0)
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

Just to make it cleaner and more readable, I reset the column headers:

```
df.columns = ['Member','Party','Vote','Paired']
```

And then I count the votes. Now, for background, there are usually around 330 votes cast in parliament. Votes for a bill are recorded as "Yea" and votes against are "Nay". However, in this case, .value_counts gives me only the Nay votes:

```
df['Vote'].value_counts().to_frame()
    Vote
Nay 118
```

I assume because, in this particular case, the first vote recorded was a "Nay". But if a particular vote started with a "Yea" (as in this case: https://www.ourcommons.ca/Members/en/votes/43/2/41), then .value_counts() would only count the "Yea"s.
Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks,

Comment: It looks like the last dataframe (i.e. `dfs[-1]`) has only Nay votes. I see Yea votes in other dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use:

```
for df in dfs:
    df.columns = ['Member','Party','Vote','Paired']
```

It sets df as the last element of the list (sets df 21 times). As InspectorG4dget says, the last DF in the list is only nay votes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I understand why that happens - and why for seemingly random numbers of records per frame. But I can't argue with the facts. :) How should I convert my list into a dataframe properly?

Comment: I get it now (sort of). The dfs[0] dataframe contains all my data and works perfectly. Thanks!